# Shield UI Bar chart Asymptote

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, charts, bar-chart, shieldui

I want to generate Asymptote of a graph. Shield UI is providing option is manually put object array in .Data function, however I want to calculate Asymptote with a function which will return an object array. This array can be passed to below .Data function to generate the same.

```
.DataSeries(dataSeries => dataSeries.Line()
 .CollectionAlias("Assimptota")
 .Data(new object[] { 89, 26, 77, 81, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }))
```

Request you to help me how can I achieve the same.

Answer (score 2):

The ShieldUI control (and no other standard chart control for that matter) does not provide automatic mapping for such a functionality. You can simply calculate all the points needed to describe the graph and pass it as standard data for the control. Other than this, there is no functionality, similar to the financial indicators, for example, that can take only a few points and map these to an Asymptotic presentation.